# Umbraco 404 with different culture not working

Tags: c#, http-status-code-404, umbraco, multilingual, umbraco7

My issue is actually close to this one: [Umbraco V6 404 not handled properly according to culture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16101384/umbraco-v6-404-not-handled-properly-according-to-culture)

I have 2 directories with different culture:

```
Content
       EN
          page1
          page2
          404
       FR
          page1
          404
```

When I go from a FR page to a 404, the culture is back in english.

It looks like it's url-based, and probably with a 404 the engine can't find a link so it sets the culture as default but I would like to maintain this culture when the user meets a 404 page.

my config:

```
    <error404>
        <errorPage culture="en-US">1187</errorPage>
        <errorPage culture="fr-FR">1189</errorPage>
    </error404>
```

How can I do that ?

I use one-level path in domains.

Example of urls:

- site/en/page1
- site/en/page2
- site/fr/page1

*I use umbraco 7.2.5*

Comment: can you try to unpublish the `EN` node structure and test the `FR` redirect to the FR 404 page?

Comment: I did it. I am not redirected to the fr 404 page.

Comment: To the default 404 page or to which page are you redirected now?

Comment: Sorry for the lack of details, I am redirected to the default 404 page aka 'Page not found

No umbraco document matches the url '/fr/dsaddsadsdas'.

This page can be replaced with a custom 404. Check the documentation for "custom 404".

This page is intentionally left ugly ;-) '

Comment: Did you set culture info on EN and FR node? (right click on FR node and set it)

Comment: Yes I did, both my root documents (EN-FR) have their culture set (en-US for the 1st one, fr-FR for the second). This is why I can use dictionary based on the culture in documents

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some reading on different forums I found that this is a common issue.
But there is one post on the [Umbraco Wiki](https://our.umbraco.org/wiki/how-tos/how-to-implement-your-own-404-handler) that maybe can help you out.

This post contains information about writing your own `404 handler`. Just create a new class that inherist from the `umbraco.interfaces.INotFoundHandler` interface which defines two properties and one method that needs to be included in your class.

Answer (score 0):

Old question but this works on Umbraco 7.x

umbracoSettings.config

```
<errors>
  <error404>
    <errorPage culture="default">1332</errorPage>
    <errorPage culture="en-US">1332</errorPage>
    <errorPage culture="sv-SE">1185</errorPage>
  </error404>
</errors>
```

web.config

Add below to `<system.webServer>`

```
<httpErrors existingResponse="PassThrough"/>
```